# IntelliJ invalidate cache except local history

Tags: intellij-idea, caching, ide, jetbrains-ide, cache-invalidation

I would like to invalidate IntelliJ's cache without deleting files local history.

It exists something to do this? I can't find anything online.

Comment: Please check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-61385, especially last few comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-61385) seems that the problem is at least partially corrected.
Maybe cache disappearing sometimes can have other, various, causes.